# Ubuntu 14.04 and XAMPP

Tags: 14.04, xampp

Installed xampp 1.8.3 on ubuntu14.04 on a laptop. I want to access files on this xampp from my desktop. What things do i need to do all this stuff. For example i want to put ubuntu.iso setup file in htdocs folder and then download this setup file from my desktop. How do connect from my desktop to this xampp to achieve this? I have a LAN cable and also a bsnl wifi router.

Comment: To get visitors attention you have construct you question as easy understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Once Xampp is started then you should be able to access it by typing the Ip address of the host of xampp. For example:

If xampp is on computer A, with an ip address of 192.168.1.100, then the only thing you should have to do on computer B is go to your Internet browser and type 192.168.1.100 in the address bar.